# When MS Access 2013 open and close odbc connections?

Tags: entity-framework, ms-access

As far as I know database connectivity technologies like the entity framework open and close connections automatically to enhance scalability.  ([Managing Connections and Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325(v=vs.100).aspx))

For example a form using asp.net mvc and the entity framework will connect to retrieve a record and them will immediately disconnect and remains disconnected until I modify the data in the controls and save it.

I wonder if the same behavior applies for an access 2013 form linked via odbc to SQL Server. Once a record is retrieved, is the connection closed until my next operation or the connection remains open until I close the form? Is the behavior configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact or existence of a connection does not change nor increase scalability for typical applications. So if you have 10, or 1000 connections, and those connections are NOT doing anything, then SQL server not doing any work, and hence no increase in scalability will occur in these typical cases.

And OFTEN there is additional chatter over the network to open the connection pull the data, close the connection.

Then when you write the data back you AGAIN have 3 steps. So you again open the connection, open the table, write the data, and then close the table!

In fact keeping the connection open means you don’t waste network bandwidth opening and closing the connection!

The MAIN reason for disconnected datasets is that such connections work far more reliable in the case when you have a poor or less than ideal connection (such as over the internet or via Wi-Fi at a coffee shop). I these cases, if the open connection command fails, then the connection does NOT occur, and you don’t pull any data. And if a bit of time delay or re-try occurs as the connection is re-attempted, then no big deal. So you grab that data and close the connection.

However, this opening, and then closing often as noted causes additional overhead. However, given how the internet works (as opposed to a typical office network), then this disconnected approach is much the norm for pulling data over the internet, or when using something like Wi-Fi. So the approach is one of expecting that a minor disconnect will and can occur.

The second “common” reason for this 3 step process is other development platforms “promote” the use of disconnected data because the forms are NOT bound to the actual data tables (or bound to a query). The downside of this disconnected approach is you thus in general have to write code to pull the data down to the client, and THEN render the data from the recordset object to the form. The result is a TON of additional work to edit data in a form. So expect the typical asp .net application to cost 5 or even 10 times as much as writing that application in Access.

In the case of Access bound form model, it eliminates the developer having to code the data pull and coding and eliminates the need of the developer to pull that data into some object, and then close that connection. Once Access establishes a connection to the SQL server, then that connection remains open until you shut down the Access application.

The keep the connection open and active has the advantage of rapid application development due to the bound forms model. So you DO NOT need to write code to pull data from the server and THEN transfer that data from some type of object into the form.

So the downside to the Access approach has little (if anything) to do with scalability. The downside is a simple break in the connection is NOT at all well handled by Access.

So if you build a form in Access that is bound to a SQL server table of say 1 million records, and you launch that form with a where clause of InvoiceNumer = 12356, then Access is smart, and ONLY pulls down the ONE record from SQL server. So in terms of scalability and performance, the use of disconnected system as opposed to the bound connected model in Access will not result in a performance difference.

However, because Access keeps that connection open, then any breakage in that connection will result in an ODBC error. Worse is Access is NOT able to recover from such errors when using bound forms – your only recourse is to restart Access.

It is certainly possible to build un-bound forms in Access, but this is NOT how Access was designed. In fact if one is going to adopt a disconnected data model in Access then Access is the wrong tool due to no wizards or “developer aids” for such an approach. So say .net has wizards built around the disconnected system, and Access has tools built around the connected system. And a LOT of functionally that makes Access such a great rapid application development tool is lost if you build un-bound forms in Access. So bound Access forms have MANY additional events that you not find in say .net forms.

So it not scalability or better performance that is lost by the bound forms approach in Access, but simple ease of development is the main feature and gain that the Access development approach results in.

A developer will STILL need and should LIMIT the number of records pulled into a form (by use of the forms “where” clause.
 (so .net forms don’t have such indulgences as a where clause).

So the major shortcoming is that Access does not recover from ODBC disconnections since it was designed to keep such connections open.

Comment: Fantastic answer ,thanks a lot! Just to be sure I understood everything I have a follow up question. Without a where will a wizard created form showing one record just going to "download" the record on screen or the entire table?

Comment: @artificer - *"Without a where will a wizard created form showing one record just going to 'download' the record on screen or the entire table?"* - Neither. Access will retrieve the primary key values and then pull the actual records in batches of 10. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16405612/2144390) for details.

Comment: Albert - *"Once Access establishes a connection to the SQL server, then that connection remains open until you shut down the Access application."* - That is not quite true. Access will automatically close an ODBC connection after 10 minutes of inactivity, even if there is still an open form that is bound to an ODBC linked table. You can confirm that with SQL Profiler. Another connection will be opened if subsequent activity on the form requires it, e.g., to write changes back to the (linked) table.

Comment: Very useful information Thompson! Any official Microsoft documentation about the subject?